# Terminal keeps saying ./studio.sh not found in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, android-studio, linux-mint

When I run `./studio.sh` I get this error for some reason:

```
`./studio.sh
 ./studio.sh: 1: ./studio.sh: which: not found
 ./studio.sh: 1: ./studio.sh: which: not found
 ./studio.sh: 1: ./studio.sh: which: not found
 ./studio.sh: 1: ./studio.sh: which: not found
 ./studio.sh: 1: ./studio.sh: which: not found
 ./studio.sh: 1: ./studio.sh: which: not found
 ./studio.sh: 1: ./studio.sh: which: not found
 ./studio.sh: 1: ./studio.sh: which: not found
 ./studio.sh: 1: ./studio.sh: which: not found
 ./studio.sh: 1: ./studio.sh: which: not found
 ERROR: Cannot start Android Studio
 Required tools are missing - check beginning of "./studio.sh" file for details.`
```

Comment: Did you read the error message? Did you do what it says?

Comment: It's saying it can't find the `which` command, but there will probably be additional dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't have the `which` tool installed.

It should be contained in the `debianutils` package.

Try to install:

`sudo apt-get install debianutils`

or reinstall:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall debianutils`